# Fenced code markdowns in posts before 2019 doesn't render correctly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, code-formatting

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/840663/816190) on Ask Ubuntu was posted in October 2016. The last revision was made then only and there answerer used fenced code markdown (```) which at that moment wasn't introduced on Stack Exchange. However, the code markdown isn't being rendered correctly. This is how it looks:

[image]

But when I click on edit, it gets rendered correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

When a post is made or edited, the Markdown is processed just once, and then the HTML that was created is cached indefinitely. This same HTML continues to be served even after changes are made to the Markdown renderer, so that posts don't have to be re-rendered every time which is an unacceptable performance hit.

When the code fence feature was implemented, developers simply modified the Markdown renderer to support it. Previous posts that were using the format still have their prior HTML rendering from the time it wasn't supported, and weren't re-rendered (or "re-baked") afterwards. When you edit one of these posts, it will be "re-baked", which will re-render it with the current version of the Markdown renderer.

Occasionally, when making a mass change to the renderer, the team will globally re-bake all posts made after the change, to allow for support. However, this is simply a "courtesy" measure and isn't always done, in part due to performance.