# Markdown preview in suggested edit and post does not match

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, markdown-preview

This is the post: [Install Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1072563)

The post looked like this before I suggested an edit:

[image]

I suggested an edit: https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1191605

If I look at the side-by-side preview of the suggested edit, the list in the post looks different from the [original view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfUbt.png).

[image]

The list numbers had brackets in original post.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348753/323179).

Comment: It's because numbered list formatting with brackets wasn't supported at the time the post was last edited, but is supported now. When a post is made, its Markdown is rendered into HTML using the renderer at the time, and that HTML [continues to be cached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/346118/377214) indefinitely until it's edited again. Other things such as post histories and suggested edits re-render the Markdown using the most current version today, so it shows as numbered list formatting in the suggested edit.